# Redirect from 1 IP from selected port to another ip

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port-redirection

This is my situation .
I am able to access my pc using my public IP. For example when I type 202.34.56.20 in browser I am send to local host age of my server.  I have setup port forward and its working. I am accessing my server having ip 192.168.1.50 from public ip using remote desktop, but I am unable to acess my router using my pubic IP and my router don't support remote management.

So whenever I have to acess my router remotely, I have to take acess of server using remote desktop then I acess my router using that system . My router IP is 192.168.1.1

So I want to configure my server port so that when I type selected port my server redirect me to my router. For example when I type my public IP for example 202.34.56.20:8080 in web browser it redirect me to 192.168.1.1:80 and I will be albe to acess my router.

So is this possible in windows. I am using window server 2019.

Comment: I am using public IP and port forwarding to get access to my system. But unable to acess router from public ip.

Answer (score 1):

> When I type my public IP of `202.34.56.20:8080` in a web browser, it would redirect me to `192.168.1.1:80`.

I think the best you could hope for here is to (possibly) set up a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

In short, you would theoretically take `202.34.56.20:8080`, redirect that IP/port combination to an internal server (e.g. `192.168.1.50`) on a specific port and then use a web server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) on ex. `192.168.1.50`, acting as a third-party, to access the web interface for `192.168.1.1`.

Offhand, I am unfamiliar enough with the capabilities of Windows Server 2019 (and specifically IIS), so I cannot say if it could act as a reverse proxy in this instance. But both [Apache](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/) and [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/download.html) are potentially capable of doing this and are currently available on Windows.

Any proxying would be done in the context of virtual hosts (Apache) or server blocks (Nginx). Note that there could still possibly be unexpected issues when attempting to proxy the router's interface.

Comment: Ok. I am trying it. Will update if it works

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am able to acess router from my public ip. Nginx did the job.  You are great. I was trying to figure it out from last 5 days

Comment: You're welcome. Good to hear you got things working. =)